# Implication of \$s \to \infty\$ in a transfer function

Tags: transfer-function

For a strictly proper transfer function with no poles/zeros at infinity, I understand that it gives \$G(\infty) = 0\$. What does it do for a proper transfer function?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it is confusing. I hope you mean \$T(\infty)\$ , evaluating the frequency space at infinity has little meaning (that I know of). What do you mean by 'proper tf'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a transfer function with more finite poles than finite zeros, the gain goes to zero as the frequency increases without bound.

For a transfer function with an equal number of finite poles and finite zeros, the gain will be non-zero as the frequency increases without bound.  This is given by the "D" term in the state space representation of the transfer function.

Comment: You're welcome.  I am happy to help.  If I answered your question, then please mark my answer as such.  Thanks!

Comment: @user551397 May I remind you what PICyPICyPICy requested. The currency on SE.EE is upvotes and answer acceptance although the word "thanks" does have some value!